# Reverse voltage PN junction (how it works?)

Tags: pn-junction

I have this block inside my circuit, which is supposed to drawn a current from the main line to the GND whenever there is this signal in the transistor base (simple diagram):

[image: Current source]

The main line can reach 50V, so I chose a BC546B which has a Vcbo of 80V and Vceo of 60V.

After that I discovered that the main line also could reach peaks of 150V and -50V sometimes. This would damage my BC546. I don't want to put a reverse diode in paralell with the transistor because I really need to block current in both ways. So I thought that maybe putting a series diode with the transistor may help me. So I did this simulation:

[image: reverse]

It seems to work. Note that when Vce>0 all the main line voltage is accross the transistor. When Vce is < 0 the main line voltage is accross the diode. Since a simple 4148 can hold up to 100V, I could choose a new transistor (MPSA42 for instance) that can hold up to 300V.

Since the diode voltage drop is not an issue because i'm dealing with current direclty, this could do the trick. Although the problem seems to be solved, how can I explain this behavior (that shows the scope)? How can I know where is the voltage drop when more than one PN junction is put in series?

**Corrected picture:

[image]

Comment: In the second schematic, the base of the transistor seems to be connected to 0V through a resistor. Is this intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Yes, its just to make sure it is not conducting. This way I could reach maximum voltage across CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the transistor put the diode in series with the collector and use a transistor capable of withstanding greater than 150V. With it drawn as you have it, the base-collector region will still see large negative voltages AND, to control the current in normal operation you need to keep R6 in the emitter without a diode.

Comment: My mistake. I've made it in a hurry. Check the corrected picture (i've edit the original post) if it's like you said.

Comment: R6 is missing but basically this should work.

Comment: But my question still remains: why it works? I have 2 devices which should block signal (diode + transistor). How can I know which one will hold the voltage difference?

Comment: the reverse current of the diode is nano amps - the transistor will behave as a transistor still but hfe will be much lower and very little voltage will develop across the transistor.

Comment: But note that what prevents a reverse current to exists (ideally) is a pn junction inside the transistor, just like in the diodes. But it I put 2 series diodes and a reverse biasing power supply like -50V, my simulation says that each of them will hold -25v. Altough if I change one of them to a transistor, almost all this reverse voltage will be accross the diode. How can I explain that?

Comment: I was trying to look to the reverse voltage vs reverse current plot in the datasheet of the diode and then compare to the transistor plot. But I could not find any transistor which shows this plot in the datasheet. Maybe this reverse current (near nanoAmperes) cause a much higher voltage accross the pn junction of the diode compared to the pn junction of the transistor. Is that it?

Comment: @user2110874 the transistor will operate (with reduced performance) - it can be regarded as a symettrical device NPN means you can swap collector and emitter and it still works with less performance - this means the transistor still conducts a bit BUT if you have some doubts put a 1Mohms resistor from collector to emitter to play safe.

Comment: Sure. But how can I know its reverse voltage drop vs reverse current so I could compare to the 4148 diode and understand why the greatest voltage drop is in the diode when reverse voltage is applied (and also the greatest voltage is in the transistor when normal voltage is applied) ?

Comment: In reverse the base collector junction will be conducting. Normally bc is a reverse diode but reversing the voltage causes it to conduct therefore protecting itself.

Comment: But wont the EB junction be reversed? This junction must block the signal like a commom diode

Comment: @user2110874 The NPN is symmetrical and it may surprise you that turning an NPN upside down does work but the current gain is much lower. The transistor will still be turned on and self protecting. I've said this several times now and questioning me more won't change my opinion. If you feel I'm wrong do some googling.

Comment: I don't feel you're wrong. You just did not answer my question so far. Q: how can I know where will be the greatest voltage (transistor or diode) since there is virtually no current? It's clear that the transistor is not acting like a simple pn junction (diode) when reversed because the result is differente when I put a diode in its place. You answered that the transistor still operates but with reduced performance, ok. That does not answer my question. It has its protection, also does not answer the question.

Comment: In both ways (forward and reverse) the transistor should block current and it does. If there is only the transistor, all the source voltage will be accross the transistor. The problem is when I have another blocking element. Could be a pair of diodes, a pair of transistors (not biased) or a transistor with a diode. Each combination between these will present a different result in terms of voltage accross the elements. I just want to know how I can estimate where or how much voltage will be accross who.

Comment: With negative supply the transistor is acting like a forward biased diode. There is 0v on the base and you try and take the collector negative. It conducts like a diode - just think about it.

Comment: But unless I've misunderstood something that you've said, think with me: taking the last picture (Corrected picture) that I've put here. Imagine that I remove the diode and now there is only the transistor blocking the current. If in reverse it will act like a forward biased diode, why does it hold the current? I've made the simulation and when I put -100v (for example) with only the transistor in the way, it holds all the -100v across it. Shouldn't be different if it was only a forward biased diode?

Comment: I agree that the CB junction might behave like a forward biased diode, but I think the most important part is the CE voltage, am I wrong? So I would like to calculate the voltage across CE when there are other blocking elements in the way like a diode or another transistor.

Comment: A transistor can operate upside down with collector = emitter and emitter = collector. In your circuit it will conduct current - Hfe will be smaller (maybe ten) but decent current flows from new collector (old emitter) to new emitter (old collector). I'm not going to talk about this again so either consider doing some research on this, accept what I say (and upvote) or do some testing. You have had a lot of good free advice on this. Regarding your simulator I can't explain other than it works from formula and doesn't expect transistors to be operated upside down.

Comment: If you don't believe me ask a new question and get answers. At least believe the collector-base will be forward biased thru a 1k resistor to ground - this will mean to get 100V across the transistor, 99.3V are across R1 (1k ohms) and 99.3mA are flowing. Do you really think that is going to happen when you have a reverse diode blocking the 100V?

Comment: I've understood what you were trying to say now. I've made some other tests and now I've got it. Sure things you told me helped me out. I just think that when I asked directly "how can I calculate reverse voltage in function of reverse current, like diodes?" you could have told me "it depends on the rest of the circuit, like when it's forward biased". But sure, you said many times it behaves like this, so I just missed the point. Sorry about that and thanks for patience.

Comment: I'm glad you got there. Good luck with it.

Comment: Without 1k resistor, you can also think of it like this: you put an ideal voltage source of -100V across the transistor. That voltage will be there regardless the current that is flowing.